# Trigger the start of a one time workflow via a data entry in a list

Tags: workflow, email, data

I have a workflow that is triggered via any change on a list and it is set to send email. Problem, the condition is set on any data point when I want it to be triggered on one data point when it changes states once.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please explain more what do you mean "any data point" or "one data point"?

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to only trigger workflow once and do not allow it to run subsequently, you could use a "Wait for change" action and use an additional field as a flag to be checked upon workflow start. So basically, under "Wait for change" add also an If condition and check whether the flag is set or not.